# Find a positive increasing function $f$ such that $f(x)x$ is not convex

Tags: calculus

I want to find a function $f$ such that $f$ is positive, $f$ is increasing, BUT $x \to f(x)x$ is not convex.

Is there a simple example? Is there an example where $x \to f(x)x$ is even concave?

Comment: Wait, $(xf(x))'' = xf''(x) + 2f'(x)$...so you need a function such that $xf''(x) + 2f'(x) < 0$ for all $x$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ on $(2,\infty)$.  Since $e^{-x}$ is small, $f$ is positive.  $f'(x)=e^{-x}>0$, so $f$ is increasing.  However $$(xf(x))''=e^{-x}(2-x)$$
This is strictly negative for all $x>2$, hence $xf(x)$ is indeed concave down on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be continuous / defined for all reals? this would fit the bill

$y = x - x^{-1}$ for x not equal to 0.